# jquery form validate plugin: field 1 not equal to field 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

heyho,

i stuck in the following problem: i try to prevent that a user can choose for the fields "username" and "email" the same values. i'm using the jquery form validate plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

would be awesome if somebody could show me the way, please see my code here:

```
// validate form    
$("#signupform").validate({

    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            remote: "/_misc/formcheck/username.cfm"
        },
        password1: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        password2: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password1"
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: "/_misc/formcheck/email.cfm"
        },
        email2: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            equalTo: "#email"
        },
        usage: "required"                       
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "please username!!",
            minlength: "username at least 2 chars"
        },
        password1: {
            required: "please password!",
            minlength: "password at least 5 chars"
        },
        password2: {
            required: "please password",
            minlength: "password at least 5 chars",
            equalTo: "password fields have to match"
        },
        email: "validate email please!",            
        email2: {
            required: "please provide correct email address!",              
            equalTo: "email fields must match!"
        },
        usage: "please check my terms!" 
    },
```

thanks in advance, michbeck

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add a custom method checking the user name and email values and add validation for that field.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/2hA8M/8/

Example  -

Method -

```
$.validator.addMethod("user_email_not_same", function(value, element) {
   return $('#name').val() != $('#email').val()
}, "* User and Email should not match");
```

Validation -

```
rules : {
     username : {
         user_email_not_same: true
     }
 },
```

Comment: thank you very much, that would work in general, yeah, but my problem is that the email-field is still empty when a user fills out the username (first field in my form), so i tried to turn it around:

  rules: {
   username: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    remote: "/_misc/formcheck/username.cfm"
   },
   email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: "/_misc/formcheck/email.cfm",
    user_email_not_same: true
   },

doesn't work this way, one more hint for me?

Comment: Attached a demo. It should still work if its empty. As if empty required would fail and even if the validation is fired with values filled in, the value should not match with empty.

Comment: do you think the remote validation calls yould be the problem?

Comment: am not sure for the remote validation calls .. as cant test it standalone. Does removing the remote validation work fine ?

Comment: yep, this works fine:

   email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    user_email_not_same: true
   },

Comment: if it works fine without remote, then must be an issue with remote validation. You might want to check if any javascripts errors which is preventing validation. The remote call and the response from it. Try using firebug for debugging.

Comment: no js errors, i checked already. maybe a solution would be to execute the remote validate call inside the method "user_email_not_same" but i'm quite unsure about syntax

Comment: so easy: just make the own function call BEFORE the remote call :-)

SOLVED, thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

This could be more flexible:

```
$.validator.addMethod("notEqualTo", function (value, element, param)
{
    var target = $(param);
    if (value) return value != target.val();
    else return this.optional(element);
}, "Does not match");
```

The call:

```
rules: {
    username: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        remote: "/_misc/formcheck/username.cfm",
        notEqualTo: "#emailId-or-anyValidJquerySelector"
    }
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/4AdWR/1/

Or directly in Html:

```
<input type="text" name="username" notEqualTo="#emailId-or-anyValidJquerySelector" minlength="2" class="required" />
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/B2hWn/1/

And this also respects you required/optional previous validations ;)

Comment: This is great, is there a way to set the validation message for notEqualTo in html attributes?

Comment: Awesome, I just included the code `$.validator.addMethod("notEqualTo", function (value, element, param){ var target = $(param); if (value) return value != target.val(); else return this.optional(element);
}, "Does not match");` at the end of the `jquery.validate.min.js` file and called the function `notEqualTo: "#sender_email"` and it works like a charm :)